# Avoid conflicts of multiple CSS frameworks and style classes

Tags: css, namespaces, bulma

I am currently implementing a plugin that gets dynamically incrusted into a DIV (not an iframe) and am currently using Bulma as my CSS framework. The issue I am having is that since this plugin is going to be integrated into many sites, it will also inherit the styles applied to the parent website.

Due to many of the classes being a standard name in many frameworks, such as column, button, form, and others, this is creating a conflict.

I have been reviewing a couple of packages that either add a prefix to these classes as well as use a namespace.

**Namespace:**

[image]

The namespace route does not work since this does avoid our plugin from not interfering with any of the other sites' styles, the site's styles still affect ours.

**Prefix Packages:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-class-prefix

The other route I was researching ways to add a prefix to all the classes from our plugin, such as -column, but I understand that this will output a CSS library with all the classes with the prefix but not my HTML files which have the `class="column"`.

I am hoping to find a solution for this, as I would think this is, although not common, a recurring issue/question and I just haven't found the proper solution for this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I am finding your issues very hard to understand especially since there is no code I can look at. If you want to override all the styles from whichever parent site you can do `*, *::before, *::after { all: unset; }`. I would have thought adding an ID on top of everything would help make your styles more specific. Editing your question and improving it will likely help more than a bounty

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@layer` css rule:

The `@layer` at-rule allows authors to explicitly layer their styles in the cascade, before specificity and order of appearance are considered.

`Example:`

```css
/* styles.css */
@layer bootstrapFramework, myPluginStyles;

@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
layer(bootstrapFramework);

@import url("https://yourPluginStyles.css")
layer(myPluginStyles);
```

Doing this will override bootstrap classes with your plugin CSS classes. Due to the order of the layers.

Check out the [browsers support](https://caniuse.com/css-cascade-layers) for the rule.

You can read more about `@layer CSS rule` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@layer

You can also checkout Web Dev Simplified Channel by Kyle on youtube. Here is the link to the video: https://youtu.be/Pr1PezCc4FU

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. That's fine. Just add a prefix to the HTML classes too. It should work.

Or you can choose to ditch CSS frameworks for the plugin and write the CSS for the necessary components. You just do a little reset for your component's HTML elements and you can expect a fairly consistent design across multiple different implementations.

I feel this may be just helpful too. [custom HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) too.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

just use `div-to-select * { all:revert }`
then add the code for the div & bulma

## Explanation

`all: revert` gets every thing to normal so it makes all other frameworks class's styles to default

Answer (score 0):

please take a look on https://agilecss.com CSS framework and UI kit, it provides some unique features not available in other frameworks, for example all the common used UI elements without JavaScript.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33456281)